# display pdf in sepearate window with python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, new-window

I have a function checking if a tkinter listbox element is a pdf file. If so, it should be shown via "ShowPdf" in a new window. I only want to view the one pdf I have chosen.

Using the function once works fine. But if I switch to another listbox element and run the function again, the pdf from the first run and the second run are arranged behind each other. So I see the pdf from the first run at first followed by the second pdf. If I run it a third time, then all three pdfs are arranged behind each other etc.

Could you please help me so that only the current pdf is shown?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf

def OnEntryLeft(event):
    cur_file=listb.get(listb.curselection())
    if (cur_file[-4:]==".pdf" or cur_file[-4:]==".PDF"):
        newWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
        pdf.ShowPdf().pdf_view(newWindow,pdf_location=cur_file,width=75,height=100).pack()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("PDF-Check", "NO pdf")
```

Comment: You can try using the `lift()` and/or `lower()` methods that `Toplevel` windows possess to control their stacking order. Here's some [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/toplevel.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the source code of `tkPDFViwer`, you will notice that `ShowPdf` uses a class variable `img_object_li` (type `list`) to store the loaded pages from PDF file.  Therefore `ShowPdf.img_object_li` will hold all the pages from those instances of `ShowPdf`. I think it is a design bug.

You need to clear the list before loading PDF file:

```py
pdf.ShowPdf.img_object_li.clear() # clear loaded pages
pdf.ShowPdf().pdf_view(newWindow,pdf_location=cur_file,width=75,height=100).pack()
```